# Selecting the next available row in SQL Server In batches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement: there is a table with 500 rows and this may increase on daily basis.

What I need is to select first 50 rows as a batch and later it should be selecting from 51 to 100 rows and so on. Table does not have an identity column and I tried using max(row number) function but am getting an error :

> Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Would be great if this error is explained as well.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to update the rows that have been processed or store them in another table.  I strongly recommend that you change the structure to have an identity primary key.

Comment: If you need help with fixing the error, you should also provide the code that threw it. Error message is pretty clear about what's wrong.

Comment: You should add a primary key. But to process a table in batches you can use [an API cursor](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68280/3690)

Comment: Why did you try `max(row number)`?   I don't understand what you were hoping to accomplish.